# Differential equation - breaking glass problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the differential equation $$\ddot{x}+\lambda \dot{x}+\omega^2 x=\frac{10^{(D/10)-8}}{3}\cos(1320\pi ) $$ where $\lambda =3.07 $ and $\omega =4.15\times 10^3 $.

I get a solution which is $$x(t)\approx Ce^{-1.535t} \cos (qt-\phi )+\frac{10^{(D/10)-8}}{38196}\cos\left ( 1320\pi t-\arctan \left (\frac{12731}{25701}\right ) \right ).$$

Now suppose I need to find $D$ so that $x\approx 1$, how would I do this, what terms can I essentially ignore? I haven't been given any initial conditions but the question is basically about breaking glass using sound aimed at the glass, which happens when $x\approx 1$.

I approximated an answer to be $D\approx 126 $ decibels by ignoring the first term. Is this right? If not could someone just point me in the right direction.

Comment: No and I don't think it's clear from the question that you can assume initial conditions like you can for some questions - for example you know that for  questions involving an object falling from a height that $x(0)=0$ - but in this question it just talks about aiming a sound at a wine glass. It's not clear, at least to me, that any initial conditions can be assumed.

Comment: Without initial conditions, hard to say ! Moreover what value did you use for $t$ in your approximation ?